Damn Vulnerable
I'm currently working on a smart contract challenge from Damn Vulnerable DeFi (or a similar CTF) and I'm trying to solve it without watching any walkthrough videos. I've been analyzing the contract and trying to identify potential vulnerabilities, but I'm stuck and would appreciate some guidance,
Can someone provide hints or suggest areas of the contract that I should focus on? I’m not looking for the full solution but just some pointers to help me progress.

This type of challenges use simplified versions of real exploits. This repo has several contract with vulnerabilities https://github.com/smartbugs/smartbugs-curated.
Similarly you could start with the best practices guide https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/. If a contract doesn't follow a recommendation it is possible that it vulnerable to some attack.
If you want more hints it will be better if you indicate which problem are you trying to solve.
